# Parallel multiplication vector-matrix

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am coding in C++ and I have a `Matrix` and a `Vector` which have to be multiplied. Both are classes that I defined and both wrap a 1-D `std::vector`; the data-type is `long long int`.
I have already parallelized the code with `std::thread`s but now I would like to take advantage of my NVIDIA GPU and code the multiplication in CUDA. In order to keep my hands as clean as possible, do you know if there exists a library that implements such an algorithm and that I can easily use? I have seen there is Thrust but from [this example](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/05/31/matrix-multiplication-cuda-cublas-curand-thrust/) it does not seem exactly what I am looking for, which instead would be something like

```
std::vector vec = ...;
std::vector mat = ...;
xyz::vector devVec = moveToGPU(vec);
xyz::matrix devMat = moveToGPU(mat);
xyz::vector devRes = multiply(devVec, devMat);
std::vector res = moveToCPU(devRes);
```

Am I asking for too much?

Comment: "do you know if there exists a library..." You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it states "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 3):

mat-vec multiplication is a standard [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) operation. However your data type is not a standard one (`float` or `double`). So it may not be the best choice to convert your data to `double`, use BLAS routines like [`gemv()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemv) and convert the result back to `long long`.

Alternatively you could create your own CUDA kernel, or use [Thrust](https://thrust.github.io/) to avoid writing kernel code but with some performance degrade. You could start from [this example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sum_rows.cu) to see how to sum a matrix row-by-row into a column vector, which is the second step for mat-vec-mul operation, after you finish the element-wise multiplication between each row the matrix and the vector.